# Django email in password reset flow: won't accept special characters

Tags: django, email, character-encoding

I am using the Django reset password flow where it sends an email to the user with a link to enter a new password. The template for this email is password_reset_email.html. I have copied this template into my own project and have customized it. However, I am not able to use special characters, such as ø. Normally, I use the entity like

```
&oslash; or &#248;
```

but they do not work- they just show up directly as written. I have not set settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET so it should be utf-8. In my .py file I have written

```
# coding=UTF-8
```

The function PasswordResetForm does the following:

```
email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html'
...
t = loader.get_template(email_template_name)
...

c = {'email': user.email,
      ...        
       }
send_mail("subject line",
            t.render(Context(c)), from_email, [user.email])
```

I have tried changing the template to .txt instead of .py, and using escape.

Edit: the error that I get is: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte

Edit. I realized that the problem is that it is not rendering at all. It's not just a special char issue. So, I'm going to ask it as a new question.

Comment: Not sooo familiar with Python, but if you want to send emails with æøå you must encode your mail header correctly. If you try to simply display the template, does æøå show up correctly?

Comment: If I open the template directly in Chrome, then the ø is displayed correctly. It seems that I can include header information when sending an email. But what should the encoding be, and then how do I write the character in the email template? I do not have to use html.

Comment: Is `send_mail` a standard python/django-function?

Comment: Is it possible that your *database* is not using a unicode character set?

Comment: My database is fine. And this is text that I write directly into the template. send_mail is standard:  from django.core.mail import send_mail

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might have something to do with mixing strings and unicode sequences. To force all of your strings in the forms file to use unicode try adding the following import at the top:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with rendering, not just special chars. I never got send_mail() to work, but am using  EmailMultiAlternatives.send()

Answered here:

[Python/Django: Email template is not rendered. Shows html tags and doesn't convert entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285976/python-django-email-template-is-not-rendered-shows-html-tags-and-doesnt-conve/13286215#13286215)