# Python/Django: Email template is not rendered. Shows html tags and doesn't convert entities

Tags: python, django, email, django-templates

I am sending emails using a template, but the template is not being properly rendered. It shows the html tags and doesn't render special chars.

It does render the context, for example if I supply it with a "username":some_name then it will properly display the username when I do {{username}}

my_template.html:

```
<p>hello &oslash;</p>
```

In views:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context

t = get_template('my_template.html')
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives("hi", t.render(Context({})), from_email, [user.email])
msg.send()
```

The received email shows up with the p tags displayed. Also, the entity appears exactly as written in the template. I'd be fine just using a .txt file except that I need the special chars to be rendered. If I write them directly in the txt file, I get an error when trying to send it.

I have also tried using django's send_mail(). Also adding an html tag to the template. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a multipart/alternative email has two parts:

1. a plain text version of the email
2. an html version of the email

so here you just gotta do #2 and add the html part!

following the example here... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types   ...you'd probably just have to add a line like this before msg.send()`

```
msg.attach_alternative(t.render(Context({})), "text/html")
```

Comment: Yes, adding that line did the trick. It was not necessary to provide an actual text alternative as in the referenced example. Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Where exactly would I add that line? Grepping though all my code and all the django code I did not see any msg.send.

Comment: ohh msg is specific to the sample code user984003 provided, you'd attach_alternative to wherever your EmailMultiAlternatives object is I suppose

Answer (score 0):

```
message.content_subtype = 'html'
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?